# Setting properties into jvm from java bundle

Tags: java, properties, jvm, jetty, bundle

I have developed a Java Bundle, however i am having a problem,

I am able to use System.setProperties() on the bundle Activator, and the change works just fine. However, if i use it outside of the Activator it just doesn't work.

The property i am changing is "javax.net.ssl", the keystore path, the type and the password. Since i am using a plugin from a 3rd party application, whenever i load a method to request a web service, it loads the Activator(), sets the properties on the JVM and is able to communicate just fine. However, if i set it inside the class i am calling the method, it doesn't work.

I have even set a proxy class, to do the job and call the method, however isn't working either, and i can't figure why.

The problem is that i want to have the path, type and password to be entered from the 3rd party application, and on the activator class i can't do it.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Are you developing an Android feature?

Comment: It is a standard java plugin, using JAX-WS for the web service client and Jetty as a server to use the bundle. The 3rd party connects to Jetty to use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found out that is itn't possible to alter the properties regarding SSL at runtime, since the old properties are cached and the JVM keeps using them, altho using getProperty returns the new property.

Comment: So is it possible to 'refresh' the JVM properties at runtime?